# Update part text value within href in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to update the text 'changethis' in below div using jquery ? I don't think the .html method will suffice here since I just want to update part of the html, not all of it.

```
<div id="test">
<a title="http://stackoverflow.com" href="http://stackoverflow.com">changethis</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If none of the answers so far answer you question, then you need to be more specific on why `.text()` or `.html()` won't work for you, giving an example.

Comment: I did, I needed to use $("#test a") instead of $("#test")

Comment: @user470184, ah I see nvm then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$("#test a").html("changed it");
```

will produce:

```
<div id="test">
<a title="http://stackoverflow.com" href="http://stackoverflow.com">changed it</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. What is the $("#test a"), I assume the 'a' updates the href, is this a jquery parameter ?

Comment: `#test a` is just a selector that selects all `a`s within `#test` - just the same as for css.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#test a').html('newText');
```

Or

```
$('#test a').text('newText');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Jquery's builtin [.text() function](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

E.G. `$('#test a').text('New Text');`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise either using a second div element within the link. Or if possible select the link element itself.

The other option is to hardcode the anchor tag into your write code

```
.html("<a title='http://stackoverflow.com' href='http://stackoverflow.com'>"+newtext+"</a>");
```

Comment: This won't work because of the quotations it needs to be like this: `.html('<a title="http://stackoverflow.com" href="http://stackoverflow.com">'+newtext+'</a>');`